# How can I remove scope from Ubuntu phone home screen?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, scopes

I've had my Ubuntu phone, a BQ E5, for a week now, and after first problems with Internet access (it's ok now), I'm getting to like it. What I'm very unhappy with, however, is the fact that the scope seems to not just sit on the home screen, but actually be the home screen at all times ... I've customized the scope and I like the idea of having a scope or scopes rather than apps, ok, but ... I want a picture of my cat again on my home screen, please! And not the blinding, bright white color as the scope background ... (but that seems to be doable, just haven't figured it out yet).

Can anyone help me, please, and tell me how I can change the home screen away from the scope and to a picture?

Thanks so much, Carol

Answer (score 1):

The scopes view is the home screen. You cannot remove it and replace it with your background image. The background image is only used for the lock screen. It is a design decision.

I suggest you contact bq support and explain that you are unable to set the background.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If "it's a design decision" means nothing can be done really, I think it was a very poor decision. Not leaving the decision up to me what I look at, makes me feel like it's not my phone really ... I will try and contact BQ Support, as you suggest. I don't quite understand why they should be able to help if it's an Ubuntu matter, but I'll try :-)

Comment: Because BQ is first tier support for their retail phones. If you have a problem with an Android version of their phone, you don't go to Google, you go to BQ (or the service provider/retailer you purchased the phone at). For retail phones that ship with Ubuntu, the same should be true.